# JQuery show and hide div from drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three combobox that has each one should display and hide the respective div if selection is made.

```
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#combobox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:visible');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
    } else{
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
    }
});


$('#combobox1').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:visible');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
    } else{
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
    }
});

$('#combobox2').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:visible');
    }    } else{
        $('.WalLDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.AppliDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
        $('.BBBDP').attr('style', 'display:none');
    }
});
</script>
  </head>
```

Three dropdown list are given :

```
<select id="combobox" name="combobox" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
        <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
        <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
    </select>
       <select id="combobox1" name="combobox1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
        <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
        <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
    </select>
     <select id="combobox2" name="combobox2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
        <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
        <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
    </select>
```

The code for div are :

```
<div style="display:block">default</div>
    <div class="WalLDP" style="display:none">content1  of Walmart OR Appliance OR  Beyond Presedential</div>
    <div class="AppliDP" style="display:none">content2 of Walmart OR Appliance OR  Beyond Presedential</div>
    <div class="BBBDP" style="display:none">content3   of Walmart OR Appliance OR  Beyond Presedential</div>
```

What i want is when any values on dropdown list is selected it should display respective div using javascript and on onchange="this.form.submit();" the dropdown list should display the respective data from database into respective div.onchange="this.form.submit();" it is working fine giving the respective record into div from db.So on submit it loads the respective record but on combobox submit page refresh and load the default div .How i can get this respective div in which data is loaded on submit?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should simplify your code and it'll be easier to manage.

As for you question, you should set value from database and update your markup every time when you change selects or get new value

For example:

```
    var value = 3; // Here you have to set value that you get from database
    var $select = $('.js-select'); // Specify your select here

    var updateBoxes = function( value ) {
        $('.js-box').hide();
        $('#box' + value).show();
    }

    var initSelects = function( value ) {
        if (value !== 0) {
            $select.val( value );
        }
        $select.on('change', function() {
            updateBoxes( $select.val() );
        });
    }

    initSelects( value );
    updateBoxes( value );
```

And HTML-markup like the following:

```
<select class="form-control js-select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="box1" style="display: none;" class="well js-box">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, doloribus!</p>
</div>

<div id="box2" style="display: none;" class="well js-box">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, doloribus!</p>
</div>

<div id="box3" style="display: none;" class="well js-box">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, doloribus!</p>
</div>
```

Also see JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4b0uyd2d/

I hope it'll help you, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: no you are using single combobox for selecting 3 div ....i have mentioned in question.The 3 div each hidden by default and shown on 3 separate combo-box selection respectively .

Answer (score 0):

By making your dependent `id` a pattern will make your life easier. For each dependent `div` use an `id` which is patterned on the `id` of its corresponding `select`. Then it would be easy for you to target which `div` to hide or show.

***Example Snippet:***

```js
$("select.cascade").on("change", function() {
  var which  = this.id, 
      div    = which + "d", 
      sel    = $(this).val();
  
  if (sel == '0') {
    $("#" + div).hide();
  } else {
    $("#" + div).show();
  }
  
  // Call form.submit here if need be
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="c1" name="combobox" class="cascade">
 <option value="0">Select one...</option>
 <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
 <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
 <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
   <select id="c2" name="combobox1" class="cascade">
 <option value="0">Select one...</option>
 <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
 <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
 <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
 <select id="c3" name="combobox2" class="cascade">
 <option value="0">Select one...</option>
 <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
 <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
 <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>

<div style="display:block">default</div>
<div id="c1d" class="WalLDP" style="display:none">content1 </div>
<div id="c2d" class="AppliDP" style="display:none">content2 </div>
<div id="c3d" class="BBBDP" style="display:none">content3</div>
```

Comment: I have saved this code as .php file and it is running it through wamp server just showing comboboxes but it is not showing hidden div on change in comboboxes